# DataGridView and CheckBoxes

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview

I'm making an application which has a page with a button and a datagridview inside.

The data comes from MySQL and the population is done this way:

```
this.ObjectsTable.Rows.Add(Objects.GetValue(index, 0), 
                           Objects.GetValue(index, 1), 
                           Objects.GetValue(index, 2), 
                           Objects.GetValue(index, 3));
```

The problem:

> I cannot check the checkbox. Literally. When I click it it just goes
>   to "pressed/onPress" state but never goes "checked".

How to fix that? And how to *get the row whose checkbox was checked*?
I want to make an array and then iterate through them.

Comment: Could you maybe show some front end code of the GridView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if your `DataGridView` is either `Enabled` or is not `ReadOnly`, if that did not help check if the `Column` is not read only.

Second part of you question answer depends if you want to immediately know which `CheckBox` has been checked or not. Is yes then use this event:

```
private void GridCellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex < 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex] is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
    {
        var check = (dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value as bool?) ?? false;

        if (check)
        {
            //checked
        }
    }
}
```

or just iterate through all rows and check value of cell with checkbox:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
      var check = (row.Cells[0].Value as bool?) ?? false;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the hijack, but I'm looking for the same answer. I had stumbled across the cellvaluechanged event as well, but the problem I had with it was that when the form is loaded and the data is populated from SQL it registers as a cellvaluechanged event and tries to execute the check. I put an if checkstate.unchecked exit sub in there, but then I get an application crash as it tries to simultaneously check the next row and exit the check. Any way around that?